# What am I missing on concurrency?

Tags: go, concurrency, goroutine

I have a very simple script that makes a get request and then does some thing with the response. I have 2 version one using a go routine and one without I bencharmaked both and there was no difference in speed. Here is a dumb down version of what I'm doing:

Regular Version:

```
func main() {
    url := "http://finance.yahoo.com/q?s=aapl"

    for i := 0; i < 250; i++ {
        resp, err := http.Get(url)
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Println(err)
        }

        fmt.Println(resp.Status)
    }
}
```

Go Routine:

```
func main() {
    url := "http://finance.yahoo.com/q?s=aapl"

    for i := 0; i < 250; i++ {
        wg.Add(1)
        go run(url, &wg)
        wg.Wait()
    }
}

func run(url string, wg *sync.WaitGroup) {
    defer wg.Done()
    resp, err := http.Get(url)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }

    fmt.Println(resp.Status)
}
```

In most cases when I used a go routine the program took longer to execute. What concept am I missing to understand using concurrency efficiently?

Comment: I believe because you have `wg.Wait()` inside the loop, it blocks there until `run` returns meaning in your 'concurrent' example, it **should** perform worse because you've added the wait guard and goroutine overhead. I believe that line of code needs to be a the bottom of main so you block until all go routines complete, rather than on each.

Comment: Also, your examples just bad because you're not actually doing any work. If you this were more complete and included the processing of responses then you would likely see a major divergence in performance as the number of concurrent requests increased. Since the only thing really taking time here is the requests/response actually going over the wire it's just not really likely to demonstrate the concept very well in the first place.

Comment: @evanmcdonnal gotcha and yeah I dumbed down the example just to show how I was calling the go routines. I know http is also a bad benchmark since it has outside factors that can contribute to slower execution times. It was more too see if I was calling the routine correctly which you pointed out I was not. Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The main problem with your example is that you're calling `wg.Wait()` within the for loop. This causes execution to block until you the deferred `wg.Done()` call inside of `run`. As a result, the execution isn't concurrent, it happens in a goroutine but you block after starting goroutine `i` and before starting `i+1`. If you place that statement after the loop instead like below then your code won't block until after the loop (all goroutines have been started, some may have already completed).

```
func main() {
    url := "http://finance.yahoo.com/q?s=aapl"

    for i := 0; i < 250; i++ {
        wg.Add(1)
        go run(url, &wg)
        // wg.Wait() don't wait here cause it serializes execution
    }
    wg.Wait() // wait here, now that all goroutines have been started
}
```